# RSA handling different between Container and Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, git, github

I have two Ubuntu environments (one Container and one machine), which handle the same rsa private key pretty differently.
The first noticable change I see in the logs, is that they identify the `type` differently:

**Ubuntu Container (Xenial):**

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.113.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: identity file /push-ssh/id_rsa type 1
```

**Ubuntu Machine (Bionic):**

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.118.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /tmp/id_rsa type 0
```

Following the sha256s to ensure the file content is that same:

```
2eb49319702ccee5acd89b6632a5dc00bb450fad6fa5de7d0f99af6c45a28412  /push-ssh/id_rsa
2eb49319702ccee5acd89b6632a5dc00bb450fad6fa5de7d0f99af6c45a28412  /tmp/id_rsa
```

Can anyone explain, how it can happen, that these types mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

> OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
>
> OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017

This is really a simple guess but I'd bet the internal identifier for the file type defined in [sshkey.c](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/%7Echeckout%7E/src/usr.bin/ssh/sshkey.c?rev=1.97&content-type=text/plain&only_with_tag=MAIN) has changed between the two versions.

You can learn more on this in the [following question on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088184/what-does-identity-file-type-mean-in-ssh-debug-messags)

Comment: Specifically, 7.6 (finally!) deleted support for the long-obsolete SSHv1 protocol and along with it the special 'rsa1' keytype which previously had enum value 0, so everything else shifted down one.